# Blender 3D models for chess pieces and board for blind players (open licence)?

Tags: chess-set

I am interested in Blender 3D models for chess pieces that can be used in a 3D printer.
I am aware of Blender 3D models for "normal" chess pieces that are available under an open licence, i.e. [this chessboard](https://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/objects/id/chessboard/) and [these pieces (just the pieces?)](https://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/objects/id/chess/) in the Blender 3D Model Repository (available under a Creative Commons licence).

However, I have an additional requirement: I would like 3D models of chess pieces and a chess board that can be used by **blind players**.

- For the **pieces**, this means that each piece has a little pin at the bottom that fits into a hole in the squares (so the pieces don't get knocked over when you check where they are). In addition, the pieces need something to distinguish white from black (e.g. an extra pin at the top of the black pieces.
- For the **board**, this means that each square has a little hole where the pins on the fit in, and the black squares are raised compared to the white squares.

You can see some examples on [ChessHouse.com](http://www.chesshouse.com/chess_for_blind_or_visually_impaired_s/475.htm) and [MaxiAids.com](https://www.maxiaids.com/large-table-top-chess-set-for-the-blind-or-those-with-low-vision).

Are there any Blender models for this? Especially under a Creative Commons licence?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about 3d printing, but you could design your own.

Windows has a program called 3D Builder with a built in chess set that you modify, as well as a 4x4 game board that can be modified and built up. 3D Builder is free on the [app store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/3d-builder/9wzdncrfj3t6).

[image: Pieces]

[image: Board]

If you get stuck, I suggest visiting [3D Printing.SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/).